# Compositor: Get the average value of an input fac

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, mathematics

I want to take an input factor, such as a mask or pass, and get the average value of the pixels within it. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender has a levels node that return:

- Mean (Average).
- Standard Deviation.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use this with Alpha, or somehow limit it? If I have an image that is mostly black and then has a colored object, I want to get the levels of that colored object. But the levels node does not seem to recognize Alpha, so I always end up with the background color being factored in too, making it useless.

Comment: @Drudge I just tested it with alpha, Alpha does not seem to be calculated in the mean. Can you share your setup?

Comment: Doh, you are correct. I chose a poor image to test it with. Well that's good news at least!